# Google Maps logging "This site overrides Array.from() with an implementation that doesn't support iterables ..."

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Since a few months my previously trouble-free working Google Maps static map display shows this in the browser console:

> This site overrides Array.from() with an implementation that doesn't support iterables, which could cause Google Maps JavaScript API v3 to not work correctly.

It's worked for at least seven years, all the sudden it no longer works, although I've not updated anything on the site. It is super annoying that obviously Google changed something that has been working for years and years, now destroying existing installations.

What do I have to do to get Maps working again? I have absolutely no idea where I can find the `Array.from()` implementation.